# Replace UID in view tab with name on user profile page

Tags: views, navigation

I'm working on a Drupal 8 site. I made a custom page view displaying special content created by the user. The menu tab shows on the user profile correctly by using Pathauto to show the correct address on the primary user profile page using a pattern of: user/[user:field_full_name].

On the tab page created by my custom view, I can't get it to show the user name, only the user ID from the page view path: /user/%user/other-work

I would like the tab's page view URL to show the user's name instead of just the user ID. I already tried different patterns in Pathauto, but it doesn't seem to have that ability. Pathauto does work for fixing the default user page URL, but none of my custom views pages I added. Does anyone know if it's possible for a custom view page like mine to show the user's name instead of the UID in the tab's URL?

Answer (score 0):

> To replace UID in view tab with name on user profile page:

follow those steps:

1. Create a user relationship :
   [image]
2. Add contextual filters with **User Name**
   [image]
   3.Configure your contextual filter (**(author) User: Name**) like this
   [image]
3. Save your configuration.

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either. The only path it will let me use is /user/%user/other-work and that continues to only show the user ID number.

Comment: I have tested it on Drupal 8.9 and also 9.1.0 it works for me

Comment: Did you change the path from `/user/%user/`? I'm doing something wrong but I just can't find it. I made a test view doing the exact steps you showed and the URL still shows the UID number.

Comment: When you configure your view go to **/user/admin/other-work** for example instead of **/user/1/other-work** you should see the articles created by admin

Comment: Okay @berramou now I see where we're crossing wires. This view is generating a menu tab that shows on the users profiles pages. The URL of the menu tab is `/user/%user/other-work`. Here is where I'm trying to get it to show with the user's name in the URL. I see that if I manually type the user's name in the URL like: `www.mysite.com/user/test-writer/other-work` it does show the page.

Comment: Somehow I need the same URL to be automatically generated so it shows when the OTHER WORK tab is clicked. The whole idea is because I designing for writers that will want their names in the URL's, on the pages, in the menu's, and everywhere else to get them noticed.